# There are m, n and r points in 3 parallel (different lines). How many triangles can be formed by those points?

Tags: combinatorics

There are m, n and r points in 3 parallel (different lines). Supposing that when taking one point from each line they're never aligned. How many triangles can be formed by those points?

Answer (score 8):

(*for the purposes of this answer I will assume orientation is unimportant, i.e. triangle xyz is the same as triangle xzy*)

Label the lines as $A$, $B$, and $C$, with points along each as $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$, $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$, and $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_r$.

According to the problem statement, for every $i,j,k$ you have $a_i,b_j,c_k$ are not colinear.

What constitutes enough information to form a triangle then?  Any three points out of the $(m+n+r)$ total points will define a unique triangle **unless** they are colinear.  The only way they could be colinear however is that they all lie on the same line.

So.  How many ways are there to choose 3 points (with order unimportant)?

- There are $m+n+r$ total points, and we want to choose 3 of them.
- $\binom{m+n+r}{3}$

How many of these groups of 3 points were in fact colinear?

- Either all three come from line $A$, all three come from line $B$, or all three come from line $C$
- $\binom{m}{3} + \binom{n}{3} + \binom{r}{3}$

For a total of:

$$\binom{m+n+r}{3} - \binom{m}{3}-\binom{n}{3}-\binom{r}{3}$$